# Getting result set from non-sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, go, sqlx

How do I retrieve data sets from non-standard MySQL "show" statement using golang? For example, "show tables", "show variables", "show engine innodb status". etc.

I cannot find any information to retrieve the result set from mysql "show" statement in Golang. Using either database/sql package or sqlx package is fine.

Comment: You can query the information_schema instead of using show I believe

Comment: @mkopriva There is nowhere you can find information "show engine innodb status" from information_schema. Read from information_schema is simple.

Comment: @edkeveked. No. I don't use gorm at all. This is using golang standard library.

Comment: @Max and you've tried show and that didn't work?

Comment: @mkopriva. I don't even know how to start it.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Here is the code. It worked!

```
var r1, r2, r3 string
row := db.QueryRow("show engine innodb status")
err = row.Scan(&r1, &r2, &r3)
```